# Clicking on an <a> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I'm trying to create a simple Greasemonkey script that periodically triggers a mouse click on an `<a>` element (that is bound to do something with JavaScript). There is always one `<a>` element inside the "awesome-div" but the class and name of that `<a>` may vary.

HTML:

```
...
<div id="awesome-div">
<a class="some random class">this randomly named link needs to be clicked</a>
</div>
...
```

Here's my userscript

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name          My Awesome Script
// @namespace     http://example.com/myawesomescript  
// @description   Not working
// @include       http://mywebsite.com/*
// @require       http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

function clickLink() {
    $('div#awesome-div').find('a').click();
}

$(document).ready(function() {  
    setInterval(clickLink, 5000); // repeat every 5 seconds
});
```

But this userscript is not working. What goes wrong?

`// @include http://mywebsite.com/*` is correct in the actual script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Greasemonkey Jquery Script to Click Links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6466856/greasemonkey-jquery-script-to-click-links)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
function clickLink() {
    var ele=document.getElementById('awesome-div');
    var a = ele.getElementsByTagName('a');
    a[0].click();
}
```

variable 'a' will contain all the anchor tags inside that div, 0 implies to the first element

You can also loop through each of the anchor elements in that div

```
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++)
{
  // a[i].click(); do whatever you want with all of these
}
```